# Duda sobre Hash MD5

Tags: java, hash, md5

Tengo un ejercicio que me pide crear un programa al que se le pase una opcion y un nombre de fichero. Y cada opción debe hacer diferentes cosas mediante hashmd5

Ahora lo que tengo es un programa que me pide un texto y a ese texto le obtengo el calculo del hash.
Necesito cambiar para que en vez de que sea un texto, sea el fichero .txt pero no se como hacerlo.

Dejo el programa como lo tengo:

```
package PrProcesos;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Clase principal
 * @author marina
 */
public class hashMd {
    /**
     * constructor
     * Si no se pasa parametro se pide por consola
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto;
        //si se pasa texto como parametro
        if (args.length==1){
            texto = args[0];
        }
        //Si no se pasa el texto como parametro
        else {
            Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Introduce el texto:");
            texto = lectura.nextLine();
        }
        //Calcular el hash md5
        System.out.print("El Hash md5 es: ");
        System.out.println(ObtenerHash(texto));
    }

    /**
     * Función para obtener el hash md5
     * @param textoEntrada
     * @return
     */
    private static String ObtenerHash(String textoEntrada){
        if (textoEntrada.equals("")){
            return "";
        }
        else {
            try {
                MessageDigest Hashmd5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte[] mensaje = Hashmd5.digest(textoEntrada.getBytes());
                BigInteger numero = new BigInteger(1, mensaje);
                StringBuilder hashSalida = new StringBuilder(numero.toString(16));
                while (hashSalida.length()<32){
                    hashSalida.insert(0, "0");
                } return hashSalida.toString();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
                System.out.println("Error al obtener el hash: " + e.getMessage());
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un stream para leer el fichero directamente como una colección de bytes y procesarlo con un DigestInputStream

```java
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"));
     DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, Hashmd5)) {
    while (dis.read() != -1) {
      // vacío
    }
}
byte[] digest = Hashmd5.digest();
```

Comment: No he probado este código, qué error te da?

Comment: He actualizado el código para usar el nombre de variables que estabas usando en tu  aplicación